# Alignment issues with IE7-8

Tags: css

I have major issues with cross browser compatibility. This picture illustrates the problem:

[image: no descr]

What code do I put in for IE7-8 so that my menu aligns properly? Right now it looks right in firefox but nothing else.

This the the menu code she had (there might be other code associated but I don't know, see [actual site](http://whitehall.aligndeliverstemp.com/)):

```
.custom .menu { 
    height:25px;
    border: 1px none; 
    float:right;

}
```

I have tried things mentioned in other threads, `overflow:hidden;` / giving a width / `margin: 0 auto` etc. Nothing works and only ends up breaking Firefox as well.

Comment: Um.. so.. where is your question ? ...

Comment: Sorry, I had a pic explaining it then seems I cannot post it yet as I am a newbie here.

What code do I put in for IE7-8 so that my menu aligns properly. Right now it looks right in firefox but nothing else.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "properly". You need to tell us what you want it to look like. It looks off in Safari on a Mac as well btw.

Comment: I want the menu to float right (as you can see from my link in firefox  but it all moves to the left in other browsers.

Comment: [link](http://whitehall.aligndeliverstemp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/web-issue.jpg)

Comment: rghh getting used to how the forum works.

PIC OF PROBLEM

Comment: [PIC OF PROBLEM](http://whitehall.aligndeliverstemp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/web-issue.jpg)

Comment: Chrome has issues. Check in Chrome!

Comment: This being your first time on the site, if one of us answer your question, be sure to select an answer.

Comment: Stop looking at CSS for now.  Your HTML is invalid and IE cannot handle that very well.  Fix the HTML... _then_ work on the CSS.

Comment: I fixed the <p align> tags as they aren't proper syntax and thaqt helped with the vertical position but I still have issues getting it to float right.

the other errors are just empty wordpress sidebar boxes. I presume they are always like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.custom .menu {
     height: 106px;
     border: 0px none;
     float: right;
}


.custom #header {
     background: transparent;
     height: 80px;
     top: -80px;
     position: relative;
     border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added this in, It seems to have done something beneficial but the right aligning, floating is still not working in IE7/8 Thanks for the code though!

Comment: It helped with the vertical placement but the menu still won't go the the right side.

Comment: Did you refresh your CSS cache? (Ctrl+F5) on the website. I just tested in [IE7](http://i.imgur.com/zKXO0.jpg) and [IE8](http://i.imgur.com/9KH74.jpg) and it seems fine to me. Can you post a screenshot of how it looks for you now?

Comment: hmm I was using Adobe browser lab to test as I am on mac and it was not working yesterday. I loaded it up today and seems fixed. I'll try al browsers and get back to ya. Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in Safari on Mac, which looks similar to the problem you've got. There are a few css issues.

```
#header { float:left; }
.menu-menu-top-container { float:right; }
```

remove:

```
#header { clear:both; }
.custom .menu { height:25px; }
```

There are a lot of issues with this site though. I'd personally start all over with both html and css. It's one of the stranger pieces of code I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Ya I hear you, I am taking it over from a different designer and its been a nightmare honestly. I'll try that out. thanks! Unfortunately I am not getting paid enough to redo it atm.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It just pushes the menu down in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have [HTML issues](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://whitehall.aligndeliverstemp.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) that are likely the cause.  Explorer, for example, hates invalid HTML and has the hardest time figuring out your intent.  Other browsers make different guesses, and your site is also broken in Safari.  Point being, unless you follow the standards, rendering will be unpredictable.

You have two empty `<ul>` elements which is not valid.

> `<ul>` requires `<li>`

```
<div id="sidebar_1" class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar_list">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="sidebar_2" class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar_list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Once you fix the HTML, *only then* work on your CSS issues.

Comment: These are created by wordpress, waiting to have widgets placed there. Thx for the reply

Comment: @user1868861, It doesn't matter how this was created. It's still _invalid_ HTML and invalid HTML is very likely to cause IE rendering issues.